# jquery animate flash object

Tags: jquery, flash, animation

I'm trying to resize a flash object (and eventually move it but first things first) in animation but it doesn't seem to work at all.

If I'm changing only the css property in Jquery it works.


**Not working animation:**

```
$('#greenbtn').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: '242px', height: '63px'}, 'fast', 'easeOutSine');
    console.log('here1');
});
$('#greenbtn').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: '228px', height: '57px'}, 'fast', 'easeOutSine');
    console.log('here2');
});
```

**Working:**

```
$('div.leftB').hover(function(){
    $('#greenbtn').css({width: '242px', height: '63px'});
});
$('div.leftB').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#greenbtn').css({width: '228px', height: '57px'});
});
```

Is the .animate() not working on flash at all or is something wrong with my code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are using another element as a trigger in your working example?

Comment: have you tried triggering the animation that selector? like `$('#greenbtn').animate( ...)` ?

Comment: I haven't tried it because the animation supposed to start on hover

Answer (score 0):

Do you even get into the event handlers in the non-working scenario?
In both cases you are effecting `#greenbtn` but the event listeners are bound to different elements.

Comment: No I do not see the console.log in the non working example.

div.leftB is the parent of #greenbtn so it's working properly for css.

Answer (score 0):

since you're able to change the css properties without animation, you could use CSS transitions for that part:

```
#greenbtn{
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
     -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
      -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
       -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
          transition: all 400ms ease-in;
}
```